# Efficient implementation of factorization machine with matrix operations?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, matrix, machine-learning, matrix-multiplication

Link is here : https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r01922136/slides/ffm.pdf (slides 5-6)

Given the following matrices:

```
X : n * d 
W : d * k
```

Is there an efficient way to calculate the n x 1 matrix using only matrix operations (eg. numpy, tensorflow), where the jth element is :

[image]

EDIT:
Current attempt is this, but obviously it's not very space efficient, as it requires storing matrices of size `n*d*d` :

```
n = 1000
d = 256
k = 32

x = np.random.normal(size=[n,d])
w = np.random.normal(size=[d,k])

xxt = np.matmul(x.reshape([n,d,1]),x.reshape([n,1,d]))
wwt = np.matmul(w.reshape([1,d,k]),w.reshape([1,k,d]))
output = xxt*wwt
output = np.sum(output,(1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid large temporary arrays

Not all types of algorithms are that easily or obviously to vectorize. The `np.sum(xxt*wwt)` can be rewritten using `np.einsum`. This should be faster than your solution, but has some other limitations (eg. no multithreading).

I would therefor suggest using a compiler like Numba.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def factorization_nb(w,x):
  n = x.shape[0]
  d = x.shape[1]
  k = w.shape[1]
  
  output=np.empty(n,dtype=w.dtype)
  wwt=np.dot(w.reshape((d,k)),w.reshape((k,d)))
  
  for i in nb.prange(n):
    sum=0.
    for j in range(d):
      for jj in range(d):
        sum+=x[i,j]*x[i,jj]*wwt[j,jj]
    output[i]=sum
  return output

def factorization_orig(w,x):
  n = x.shape[0]
  d = x.shape[1]
  k = w.shape[1]
  
  xxt = np.matmul(x.reshape([n,d,1]),x.reshape([n,1,d]))
  wwt = np.matmul(w.reshape([1,d,k]),w.reshape([1,k,d]))
  output = xxt*wwt
  output = np.sum(output,(1,2))
  
  return output
```

**Mesuring Performance**

```
n = 1000
d = 256
k = 32

x = np.random.normal(size=[n,d])
w = np.random.normal(size=[d,k])

#first call has some compilation overhead
res_1=factorization_nb(w,x)
t1=time.time()
for i in range(100):
  res_1=factorization_nb(w,x)
  #res_2=factorization_orig(w,x)

print(time.time()-t1)
```

**Timings**

```
factorization_nb: 4.2 ms per iteration
factorization_orig: 460 ms per iteration (110x speedup)
```

Answer (score 0):

For an einsum implemtnation in pytorch, it would be something like

```
V = torch.randn([50, 10])
x = torch.randn([50])
result = (torch.einsum('ik,jk,i,j->', V, V, x, x)-torch.einsum('ik,ik,i,i->', V, V, x, x))/2
```

where we subtract the contribution from the feature weight being dotted with itself.